# Associate a buffer with a process

Tags: python, shell, elpy, comint

I am using Python with `elpy`. I am trying to use a Python shell opened on the remote computer using a `shell` buffer. I can cheat `elpy` by renaming the `shell` buffer with Python running in it to `*Python*`. It works, but it takes a while for `elpy` to send the code to the `*Python*` buffer. In ESS, there is a cool feature `ess-remote` that converts an R instance opened in `shell` buffer into an inferior ESS buffer. I wonder, whether there is en efficient way of doing the same with `elpy`.

Comment: Tangential to your actual question, but there is *surely* a way to start a python REPL from within Emacs, rather than running it from a shell?

Comment: Yes, but the key here is the remote connection. I connect to remote high performance computing facilities using `ssh` through `shell` buffer, type in either `R` or `ipyton` and use the resulting buffer with scripts in my local machine. I could use `tramp` but I find it cumbersome. I think this seems to work fine with `Spacemacs` but it doesn't use `elpy` and the thing that bugs with me it is that their Python shell does not echo the input sent to the shell at all. Also, I had some problems with `tramp` when jumping through multiple machines.